# @page margin property does not apply ony when the value is a variable css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a css stylesheet like so:

```
:root {
  --main-font: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  --margin: 10cm;
}

@media print {
  *:not(span) {
    font-family: var(--main-font);
  }
  @page {
    size: A4;
    margin: var(--margin);
  }
}
```

`main-font` is working as expected, but `--margin` is not. When printing the window the font changes with `--main-font` value, but margin is set to default. The strange thing is that if I change @page `margin` value to a static one, 
like: `margin: 10cm` it works! I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are allowed to use any value with margin inside `@page`. I didn't find a clear statement about this in [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-page/#at-page-rule) but within [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) page you can read:

> Note: The W3C is discussing how to handle viewport-related `<length>` units, vh, vw, vmin, and vmax

So I supposed CSS variables are also ignored for similar reasons

Comment: I will update the answer if I find a clear indication on what is allowed within margin

Comment: Thank you for answering! If that's not allowed how come that if I hard code a value in it, it works? It prints the document with the correct margins!

Comment: @clapmemereview both are different, it doesn't matter the content of the variable if the system doesn't allow CSS variables. The parser won't handle them the same way